# How to display voltage on OLED?

Tags: driver, oled, sensing

The basic idea is to make an OLED voltage meter.
I idealy want to use as little parts as possible.

If my understanding is correct I would need a voltage sensing circuit which would give feedback to a driver, but I don't know how to drive OLED screen.
The screen I plan to use will be a 8 pin 128x32 SPI interface screen. Would an ATTiny85 work?
Thanks

Comment: 8 Pins, so probably some kind of serial bus to tell the display which pixels to activate (or what text to display.)  Other than that, you need the data sheet to see how to control the thing.  You will need some kind of microprocessor.  The Arduino would be a good place to start.

Comment: SPI only tells you how the wires are connected and the timing for sending the data bits.  It doesn't tell you (or us) anything about the content of the data.  You must get that from the datasheet.  It would be nice of you to post a link to the datasheet here as well.

Answer (score 2):

> I don't know how to drive OLED screen

So look it up.  Read the datasheet to see what commands it has, then program the microcontroller to emit those commands as needed.  This is what anyone else here would need to do too when faced with a new display they haven't previously used.

Considering that the display is specified as "128x32", the commands probably only give you ways of lighting pixels.  That means you have to do the character generation yourself if you want to display characters.

From the level of knowledge implied by your question, the above is over your head.  Go buy a meter.  It seems you want something called a *panel meter*.  Those sense a voltage and drive a display, but are intended to be integrated into bigger devices.  These things come in many flavors, including backlit or not, LCD, LED, different character sizes, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Typically these displays use something like a Solomon [SSD1306](http://www.solomon-systech.com/en/product/display-ic/oled-driver-controller/ssd1306/) controller chip. You **will** need a fairly powerful micro to buffer the display bitmap- the displays are usually pretty dumb.

I suggest considering buying the display from someone that provides proper datasheets and an Arduino library for driving the display. You can then use an inexpensive Arduino or use the MCU such as the Microchip ATMega328 directly. Using the internal ADC you can probably be up and running a couple hours after getting the parts.

If you buy something without data and support it won't be easy.

Once you get it running you can consider porting the firmware to some other platform if you like.